# Is there an R (ggplot or other) to make a line/segment width increase

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, draw, segment

[image]

I want to draw this type of line/segment in R.

Comment: Nope, not directly (I believe). Either break it up into a sequence of increasing-width sub-segments (less-smooth), or calculate the boundaries and use `geom_polygon` (more work).

Answer (score 1):

The `ggforce::geom_link2()` function can interpolate aesthetics between two points on a line.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2), y = c(1, 2),
  width = c(1, 2)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_link2(aes(size = width),
             lineend = "round")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: OK, I stand corrected, it does not look painful at all!

Comment: Yeah the ggforce package has some amazing stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, I think, "Yes, of course, because `ggplot2` is amazing and you can do anything" and, at the same time, "unfortunately it's going to be at least a little bit painful".

Here is my best approximation of your image using only points and lines:

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(1, 10, length = 200)
y <- - 2 * x
dat <- data.frame(x, y)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, size = x ** 2)) +
  geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(aes(size = x ** 2 * 0.7), 
             data = dat[c(1, 200),],
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_void()
```

And the result looks pretty decent, in my opinion.

[image: Black and white]

The greatest advantage of this technique is that it allows you to color your line, and get beautiful graphs like this!

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: I think the best solution is to use geom_link, but the problem is that I can't customize the size of the segment!
I have this dataframe:
df <- data.frame(x=(60,69,50), y=c(0,14,75), x2=c(80,78,75), y2= c(72,10,92))

ggplot(pass_data) +
  geom_link(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = x2, yend = y2, alpha = 0.1, size = stat(index)), lineend = "round")

I tried to modify the size but I didn't figure out how. (size = stat(index)  is the default size)